# Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка при смене юзернейм

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ef

При попытке изменить имя пользователя (username) система не может найти пользователя по указанному имени пользователя.

Это вызывает сообщение об ошибке "User not found", поскольку приложение не может найти соответствующего пользователя в базе данных для обновления.

Хотя пользователь в бд существует. Как исправить это и дать возможность сменить юзернейм?

Верстка:

```
@model MyViewModel;
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/profileSettings.css" />
<body>
    <form class="row" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="~/Settings/ProfileSettings">

    <div class="container1 mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 pb-5">
                <div class="author-card pb-3">
                    <div class="temp">
                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            var username = User.Identity.Name;
                            var currentUser = Model.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

                            <div class="author-card-details">
                                <h5 class="author-card-name text-lg">@currentUser.Username</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="author-card-avatar">
                                <img id="avatar-preview" src="@Url.Content(currentUser.ImageUrl)" alt="">
                                <!--https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png-->
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="author-card-profile">
                        <div class="col-12 column">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/*">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8 pb-5">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                var currentUser = Model.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == User.Identity.Name);
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="account-username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@currentUser.Id" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="account-username" value="@currentUser.Username" required>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="account-email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="account-email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="account-pass">New Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="account-pass">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="account-confirm-pass">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="account-confirm-pass">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <hr class="mt-2 mb-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h3>Your post statistics</h3>
                                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                                {
                                    var username = User.Identity.Name;
                                    var currentUser = Model.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
                                    if (currentUser != null)
                                    {
                                        var userStatistics = Model.PostStatistics.FirstOrDefault(ps => ps.Id == currentUser.PostStatisticsId);
                                        if (userStatistics != null)
                                        {
                                            <p>Likes: <span id="like-count">@userStatistics.LikeCount</span></p>
                                            <p>Dislikes: <span id="dislike-count">@userStatistics.DislikeCount</span></p>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <p>Statistics not available for the current user.</p>
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <p>Current user not found in the database.</p>
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <p>User not authenticated.</p>
                                }
                                <img src="~/img/like.png" width="50" alt="Like" />
                                <img src="~/img/dislike.png" width="50" alt="Dislike" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-12">
                        <hr class="mt-2 mb-3">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox d-block">
                                <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" id="subscribe_me" checked>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="subscribe_me">Subscribe me to Newsletter</label>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-style-1 btn-primary" type="button" id="updateProfileButton" data-toast data-toast-position="topRight"
                                    data-toast-type="success" data-toast-icon="fe-icon-check-circle" data-toast-title="Success!"
                                    data-toast-message="Your profile updated successfuly.">
                                Update Profile
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/profileSettings.js"></script>
</body>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var avatarInput = document.getElementById('avatar');

    function showAvatarPreview() {
        var file = avatarInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            $('#avatar-preview').attr('src', reader.result);
        };

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    avatarInput.addEventListener('change', showAvatarPreview);

    $('#updateProfileButton').click(function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var avatarFile = avatarInput.files[0];
        formData.append('avatar', avatarFile);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Settings/ProfileSettings',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Аватар оновлено успішно.');
                showToast('success', 'Success!', 'Your profile updated successfully.');
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.error('Помилка при оновленні аватарки:', error);
                showToast('error', 'Error!', 'Failed to update your profile.');
            }
        });
    });

    function showToast(type, title, message) {

    }

    showAvatarPreview();
});
```

Контроллер:

```
using DataAccess.Data;
using DataAccess.Data.Entities;
using Forum_MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace Forum_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class SettingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ForumDbContext context;

        //public HomeController()
        //{
        //}

        public SettingsController(ForumDbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        //public IActionResult ProfileSettings()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        public IActionResult ProfileSettings()
        {
            var posts = context.Posts.ToList();
            var users = context.Users.ToList();
            var postStatistics = context.PostStatistics.ToList();

            MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel
            {
                Posts = posts,
                Users = users,
                PostStatistics = postStatistics
            };
            return View(model);
        }

        //[HttpPost]
        //public IActionResult ProfileSettings(IFormFile avatar)
        //{
        //    if (avatar != null && avatar.Length > 0)
        //    {
        //        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        //        var currentUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

        //        if (currentUser != null)
        //        {
        //            var avatarPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/img/people/", avatar.FileName);
        //            using (var stream = new FileStream(avatarPath, FileMode.Create))
        //            {
        //                avatar.CopyTo(stream);
        //            }

        //            currentUser.ImageUrl = "/img/people/" + avatar.FileName;
        //            context.SaveChanges();
        //        }

        //        return Ok();
        //    }

        //    return BadRequest("No avatar file provided.");
        //}

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ProfileSettings(EditUserViewModel model)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Model Id: " + model.Id);
           
            DataAccess.Data.Entities.User userEntity = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == model.Id);

            if (userEntity != null)
            {
                userEntity.Username = model.Username;

                context.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine("Username updated: " + model.Username);

                return RedirectToAction("ProfileSettings");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User not found.");
                ViewBag.Message = "User not found.";
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```